# Grouping based on IF condition is not working

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a BIP report in which I have a parent group as (`<?for-each-group:G_1[./TICKET_JOBNUMBER=$JobNum];./TICKET_JOBNUMBER?>`) and under that I have another group that is needed to be selected based on report parameter $date. That is, I am doing following:

```
<?if@inlines: $date = "" OR $date = null?>
<?for-each-group:current-group();./TICKETNUM?>
<?end if?>
<?if@inlines: $date != "" ?>
<?for-each-group:current-group()[./TICKET_TICKETDATE=$date];./TICKETNUM?>
<?end if?>
```

But this is giving unwanted output. I want each `<?for-each-group:current-group();./TICKETNUM?>` as separate but with my IF conditions it is generating a consolidated output but not a separate record for each group.

Currently I am seeing following:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

The IF conditions works if put them individually but it does not work when i put them together.

Link to download rtf and sample xml.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6h6ENsGzjB7Gfzp6vqDlbddREWitS5f/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwMqtV5PxVmGSySbNllVDIlbK_3cdVaK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Dear Experts, I am still stuck in this issue that if the $date is present then it should be part of the filter and if it is not present then it should not be a part of this filter expression..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll want to use the `@section` to split pages for the new groups, when you have the correct grouping/regrouping in the correct spots.
2. The `for-each` and/or `for-each-group` should only be in a table cell if you are going to be repeating that specific row/section. I see you have them in the first cell of the top table, that's not going to work to repeat the pages. Put them before/outside the table.
3. You only need the current-group() if you are already in a grouping section, and you want to refer to the elements you have grouped. So it shouldn't be in the first grouping.
4. I don't get what you are trying to do with the if statements. Generally, if you want a condition for one of the records, just put the if statement just inside the for-each/end for-each.
5. The inlines is only if you are doing something in the middle of a sentence, and you don't want a new line after the logic. From what I can tell, you don't need it here.

Sounds like you want something like this

```
for-each-group@section:DATA_DS/G_1;TICKETNUM
[header section and table]
[Line]
for-each:current-group();
[line content]
end for-each
end for-each-group
```

Hopefully that gets you going in the right direction. Seems like you have quite a few problems, so its hard to tell exactly what you want. And in the spirit of StackOverflow, I don't want to make the whole solution for you, just solve the one problem you have. The BI Publisher documentation is actually pretty good. If you run into some trouble, try starting smaller, get that to work, then grow it from there, making sure each new addition works as you add it.

Comment: Thank you @EdHayes. My only problem is that if $date is present then report will apply the filter and if $date is not present then $date filter will not be applied.

Comment: Why not put that in your data extract/SQL? If you wont use the data, then why extract it to begin with?

Comment: I am using CSA (Custom Subject Area) to create data model and no sql is being used.